# MXMLC Ant Task : how to use "includes" notion?

Tags: ant, include, mxmlc, build.xml

I would like to use includes element in my **MXMLC ant task**. With Ant cmd line it's easy :

```
<java jar="bla/mxmlc" fork="true" failonerror="true">

<arg value="-includes"/>
<arg value="FlexMonkeyTestController"/>
```

But in MXMLC ant task, i can't resolve it :

```
<mxmlc 
file="${src.dir}/${trinity.project}.mxml"
    ...
maxmemory="512m">
<includes>
        <symbol>FlexMonkeyTestController</symbol>
</includes>
```

So, which is the good syntax ?

Thank you very much

Regards

Anthony

Comment: http://www.gorillalogic.com/forumpost/1420

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<mxmlc file="${src.dir}">
    <includes symbol="yourClassName"/>
    <includes symbol="yourOtherClassName"/>
    .................
</mxmlc>
```

[MXMLC in ANT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a60.html)